What does the 'basics' tag mean?
We now have 7 questions tagged 'basics'. What does this tag actually mean? In my opinion, it is too ambiguous and we should remove/change it.

Good catch.  This tag is an example of a "meta tag", and is widely considered a bad idea on StackExchange sites.  See e.g. The Death of Meta Tags - Blog – Stack Exchange.
The best approach available to us now is to nip it in the bud: remove the tag from all the questions.

Should this tag be replaced with 'faq'?

@ripper234 That would also be a meta tag, and is similarly deprecated.
